# twbs-bootstrap-sass + rails 4 not showing glyphicons on production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, glyphicons, bootstrap-sass

I'm using [twbs-bootstrap-sass 3.1.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (installed using bower) working with Rails 4.0.2

The problem is that **glyphicons** are not working in production environment.

I have a app.css.scss file with the following:

```
$icon-font-path: '/assets/twbs-bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
```

This is working in development environment but in production, inspecting (using chrome), I have this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://someapp.com/assets/twbs-bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

I changed **$icon-font-path** to **/fonts** to make a test. In production disappear the 404 error but, I can't see the icons working. This breaks development configuration too.